# Collapsing Categorical Feature Levels in Python StatsModels OLS output

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I am trying to create a multiple linear regression model to predict
the rating a guest gives to a hotel (Reviewer_Score) in Python using statsmodels.

**Review_Total_Negative_Word_Counts** is how long their negative comments about the hotel are

**Total_Number_of_Reviews** is how many reviews the hotel has

**Review_Total_Positive_Word_Counts** is how long their positive comments about the hotel are

**Total_Number_of_Reviews_Revewier_Has_Given** is how many reviews the guest has given on the site

**Attitude is a categorical variable:** GOOD or BAD

**Reason is reason for visit** (Leisure or Business)

**Continent** is the continent which the guest came from (multiple levels)

**Solo** is whether the traveler is a solo traveler ('Yes' or 'No')

**Season** is during which season the guest stayed at the hotel ('Fall', 'Winter', 'Summer', 'Spring')

As you can see, I have some numeric and also categorical features.

My code so far is:

`import statsmodels.formula.api as smf`

```
lm = smf.ols(formula = 'Reviewer_Score ~ Review_Total_Negative_Word_Counts + Total_Number_of_Reviews + Review_Total_Positive_Word_Counts + Total_Number_of_Reviews_Reviewer_Has_Given + Attitude + Reason + Continent + Solo + Season', data = Hotel).fit()
```

`lm.params`

`lm.summary()`

My issue is that when I look at the parameters (slopes and intercept estimates) also P-values, they look like:

[image]

[image]

The levels of each of the categorical features are included and I just want to have an output that shows us the slopes and p-values for numeric and categorical features (NOT the slopes and p-values for each level in the categorical features!)

Essentially, I want the slope output to look like:

Intercept

Total_Number_of_Reviews

Review_Total_Positive_Word_Counts

Total_Number_of_Reviews_Revewier_Has_Given

Attitude

Reason

Continent

Solo

Season

How would I do something like this to collapse the levels and just show the significance and slope value for each of the variables?

Comment: There is no single slope value for a categorical variable like "continent", but it is possible to compute the statistical significance of the entire category, e.g. for the null hypothesis that the rating does not depend on continent. This can be done automatically with `results.wald_test_terms()` where `results` is `lm` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, each of your original inputs to your model is being converted into dummy variables.*

The reason this clashes with your expectations, I suspect, is that you have three types of variables you call categorical in your model:

1. Temporal ("Season")
2. Binary ("Attitude", "Reason", "Solo")
3. Categorical ("Continent")

Only`Continent` is truly non-binary categorical as there is no way to order the continents in a hierarchy without any further information. For "`Season`" the model/program has no indication that there are only four seasons, or that they occur in a temporal order. With the binary variables, it similarly doesn't know that there are only two possible values.

I recommend converting binary variables to `1`,`0`, or `Nan` (you could first use a lambda function, followed by [pd.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)).

For "Season" specifically, it sounds you want something more akin to "time of year, indicated by season/quarter." I'd map the seasons to `1,2,3` or `4`.

For the "Continent" you could rank the continents by how many reviews you have from each, and convert each continent to its respective rank... but you'd be regressing on something more akin to a blend of "continent" + "population from originating continent."  (This, of course, may be useful to do anyways). Or, you could keep the dummy variable encoding that was already utilized.

Alternatively, you could come up with a random mapping for the continent, but include some indicator of the relative population from each continent in addition.

*To make this explicit, you can use [pd.get_dummmies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)